# WordPress is redirecting a link to a subdomain automatically

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, hyperlink, permalinks

So I have a link on my blog's menu. It's set up to go to a subdomain housing a forum (forum.secdefus). Another link on the menu is set up in exactly the same way and works fine.

However, this link shows as correctly in the bottom let hand corner of Chrome. When I click it, it takes me to http://secdefus.com/forum. (which obviously doesn't exist).

I'm led to believe this is an issue with the rewrite settings in my site's .htaccess, but I'm not sure how to rectify it. You can reproduce this by going to http://secdefus.com and clicking the "Forum" link.

Thanks.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: So, what does your .htaccess file look like? :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be more of a webhosting problem. Probably your hoster automatically redirects subdomain.domain.tld to domain.tld/subdomain if the subdomain is not found.

Besides that I can reach your forum via [www.forum.secdefus.com](http://www.forum.secdefus.com), so you might just want to fix the link in the blog menu.

Comment: The thing is I'm not sure how to fix the link. The subdomain does exist, but clicking the link (which looking at the HTML goes to the correct subdomain) automatically redirects to that.

Comment: Well, if the links are set up from WordPress, you can find the menus under "Design" -> "Menus". Probably this link can point you there: http://www.secdefus.com/wp-admin/nav-menus.php